# Laravel 5.4 set and increment custom session variable

Tags: php, session, laravel-5

Im new to Laravel. Im trying to set a counter of failed login attempts by using sessions. However I not able to make it work. Here is my UserController handling registration, login and logout. I wanna have a global variable, which I can access from the login form and force user to use CAPTCHA if there is more than 2 failed logins

```
public function postSignIn(Request $request)
{
   $failedAttempt = Session::get('FailedAttempts');
   if(!isset($failedAttempt)) $failedAttempt = 0;

    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required'
    ]);
    if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request['email'], 'password' => 
           $request['password'], 'active' => 1])) {
        return redirect()->route('dashboard');
    } else {
        $failedAttempt++;
        Session::put('FailedAttempts', $failedAttempt);
        dd("Counter: " . $failedAttempt); //<- Always 1!!!
    }
```

`$failedAttempt` never gets incremented on the next failed login attempts. I've tried `Session::set('FailedAttempts', $failedAttempt);`, `session(['FailedAttempts' => $failedAttempt]);` but still no luck

Answer (score 0):

i am sure you are making mistake at some point . try this to make a request to insert / put value to session

```
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/how-to-set-a-session-variable?page=1
```

Answer (score 0):

the secret of non persisting session I still don't know, but my solution was to use `Session::save()`:

```
Session::put('FailedAttempts', $failedAttempt);
Session::save();
```

I found my answer here: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/l5-sessions-dont-persist

Some people blame Nginx+php-fpm for that